# How to traverse a path in a table with id & parentId?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Suppose I have a table like:

```
id    |   parentId   |  name
 1          NULL         A
 2            1          B
 3            2          C
 4            1          E
 5            3          E
```

I am trying to write a scalar function I can call as:

`SELECT dbo.GetId('A/B/C/E')` which would produce "5" if we use the above reference table. The function would do the following steps:

> 1. Find the ID of 'A' which is 1
> 2. Find the ID of 'B' whose parent is 'A' (id:1) which would be id:2
> 3. Find the ID of 'C' whose parent is 'B' (id:2) which would be id:3
> 4. Find the ID of 'E' whose parent is 'C' (id:3) which would be id:5

I was trying to do it with a WHILE loop but it was getting very complicated very fast... Just thinking there must be a simple way to do this.

Comment: You should try to avoid using scalar function as much as possible. They are horribly inefficient. Even worse when you start throwing loops inside them. This sounds to me like a very typical recursive cte. Not really sure though why you would pass this a delimited list of names.

Comment: @SeanLange - thank you, am aware of the inefficiencies of a scalar function - this is just a requirement I have.

Comment: Strange requirement but whatever. If you really want some help can you post some details? Is this a recursive query or are you just trying to parse a delimited list and do a query for each value?

Comment: A recursive query would be best here, but I don't understand your requirements. You input the value `'A/B/C/E/'` but you get out `5`. Why 5?

Comment: I think I understand now. You really need to simply pass in 'A', not the whole tree. Then let your recursive cte figure out the rest of the path.

Comment: @SeanLange That's what I was thinking. You pass in a single value and you get out the bottom node of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it based on @SeanLange's recommendation to use a recursive CTE (above in the comments):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetID 
(
    @path VARCHAR(MAX)
)

/* TEST:
SELECT dbo.GetID('A/B/C/E')

*/
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID INT;

    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT p.id ,
               p.parentId ,
               CAST(p.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS name
        FROM tblT p
        WHERE parentId IS NULL

        UNION ALL
        SELECT p.id ,
               p.parentId ,
               CAST(pcte.name + '/' + p.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS name
        FROM dbo.tblT p
        INNER JOIN cte pcte ON
            pcte.id = p.parentId
    )
    SELECT @ID = id
    FROM cte
    WHERE name = @path

    RETURN @ID
END
```

Answer (score 3):

`CTE` version is not optimized way to get the hierarchical data. ([Refer MSDN Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2011/04/28/optimize-recursive-cte-query/))

You should do something like as mentioned below. It's tested for 10 millions of records and is 300 times faster than CTE version :)

```
Declare @table table(Id int, ParentId int, Name varchar(10))
insert into @table values(1,NULL,'A')
insert into @table values(2,1,'B')
insert into @table values(3,2,'C')
insert into @table values(4,1,'E')
insert into @table values(5,3,'E')

DECLARE @Counter tinyint = 0;

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#ITEM') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #ITEM

CREATE TABLE #ITEM
(
 ID int not null 
,ParentID int
,Name VARCHAR(MAX)
,lvl int not null
,RootID int not null
)

INSERT INTO #ITEM
    (ID,lvl,ParentID,Name,RootID)
SELECT   Id
        ,0 AS LVL
        ,ParentId
        ,Name
        ,Id AS RootID
FROM            
    @table
WHERE
        ISNULL(ParentId,-1) = -1

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter += 1
        insert into #ITEM(ID,ParentId,Name,lvl,RootID)
        SELECT  ci.ID
                ,ci.ParentId
                ,ci.Name
                ,@Counter as cntr
                ,ch.RootID
        FROM    
            @table AS ci
        INNER JOIN
            #ITEM AS pr 
        ON
            CI.ParentId=PR.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            #ITEM AS ch
        ON  ch.ID=pr.ID
        WHERE           
                ISNULL(ci.ParentId, -1) > 0
            AND PR.lvl = @Counter - 1
END

select * from #ITEM
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of functional rcte based on your sample data and requirements as I understand them.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    id int
    , parentId int
    , name char(1)
)

insert #Something
select 1, NULL, 'A' union all
select 2, 1, 'B' union all
select 3, 2, 'C' union all
select 4, 1, 'E' union all
select 5, 3, 'E'

declare @Root char(1) = 'A';

with MyData as
(
    select *
    from #Something
    where name = @Root

    union all

    select s.*
    from #Something s
    join MyData d on d.id = s.parentId
)

select *
from MyData
```

Note that if you change the value of your variable the output will adjust. I would make this an inline table valued function.

Comment: beat you to it by 3 minutes :-) Thanks for the tip!