# Select hierarchy from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table ServiceItem that has Id, ParentId and some properties like Name, Description and so on. Max level of hierarchy is 2. I need a query that selects rows with some condition, for example `Name = '123'` and its parent row to get smth like:

```
Id  ParentId  Name
1   NULL      '12' 
2   1         '123'
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM ServiceItem si
WHERE si.Name = '123'
    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM ServiceItem syst
            JOIN ServiceItem si2
                ON si2.ParentId = syst.Id
        WHERE syst.Id = si.ParentId
            AND si2.Name = '123'

    )
```

But it returns parent and all of it's children. Is there any chance to do it with one query? I'm using T-SQL to do it.

It's differs from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197500/how-to-traverse-a-path-in-a-table-with-id-parentid) because i need to get a bunch of rows, not only Id by path and conditions in my query could be different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to traverse a path in a table with id & parentId?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197500/how-to-traverse-a-path-in-a-table-with-id-parentid)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql server CTE and recursion example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example).  You'll have to modify the query to start the tree with the bottom of the tree instead of the top, but it's essentially the same syntax.

Comment: Then specify what the expected output is. The way you described it, you **are** looking for recursive CTE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Common Table Expression with recursion:

```
WITH cte AS
  (
    SELECT     *
    FROM       ServiceItem
    WHERE      Name = '123'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM       ServiceItem si
    INNER JOIN cte
            ON cte.ParentId = si.Id
  )
SELECT * FROM cte
```

For a more in-depth example, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS
  (
    SELECT     *
    FROM       ServiceItem
    WHERE      Name = '123'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     *
    FROM       ServiceItem si
    INNER JOIN cte
            ON cte.ParentId = si.Id
  )
SELECT * FROM cte
```

It's a good query, but I also found this one:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM ServiceItem si
WHERE si.Name  = '123'
    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM ServiceItem si2
        WHERE si2.Name = '123'
            and si2.ParentId = si.Id
    )
```